# Parameterized Query in Google BigQuery using GOLANG V2 API

Tags: go, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, parameterized

Im currently unable to use parameterized queries to Google BigQuery using the V2 API in GOLANG. Typically without the paramters the code to process the query would be:

`database_query := client.Query(report.Query)
    database_query.QueryConfig.Dst = table_result
    job, err := database_query.Run(ctx)`

assume that we dont use the named paramters. lets mock 2 parameters and append this to the request as expected from the API(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/master/bigquery/query.go) :

```
var params [2]string
params[0] = "currency"
params[1] = "price"

ParametersL := make([]bigquery.QueryParameter, 0)
for _,element := range params {
    temp := bigquery.QueryParameter{}
    temp.Value=element
    ParametersL = append(ParametersL,temp)
}

database_query := client.Query(report.Query)
database_query.QueryConfig.Dst = table_result
database_query.QueryConfig.Parameters= ParametersL
```

provided you manage to squeeze the '?' into the appropriate place into the query you either get a error prompting missing , after FROM or the other ? is not recognized. The same goes for named paramters using @. Am I missing something cruzial or is the paramters not supported for GOLANG API?

Comment: Is case someone else looks into this the error log is: Job failed with error {Location: "query"; Message: "Syntax error: Trailing comma before the FROM clause is not allowed at [1:680]"; Reason: "invalidQuery"} 
and im printing out the array of input to make sure its string: 
the string%!(EXTRA string='autoRecurring')

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `UseStandardSQL` as part of `QueryConfig`, since query parameters are supported only with [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/). You will also need to make sure to set the `Type` attribute of the `QueryParameter`s, which should be `"STRING"`. While positional parameters are supported, of course, I would still suggest using named parameters, since they make refactoring easier if you need to modify the query string at some point.

Comment: I tried the standard SQL with no effect. How am I supposed to set a type on QueryParameters when its a slice of QueryParameter (which only has Fields name and value).

Comment: Also IF you look into the https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/master/bigquery/query.go you will see that in the end of the file LegacySQL is disabled for either IF We set parameterns or send the standard SQL true. So IT should not matter

Comment: is maybe needed for feedback

Comment: I'm not able to provide any additional help, unfortunately. I have not worked with the Go library myself, but I tried to provide suggestions based on the API. I filed a [request for documentation in the public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36169533).